# Cloudformation parameter ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https' is faling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I working on the cloud formation template which will create an s3 bucket and assign cloud front and CloudFront origin to the s3 bucket and create an s3 bucker policy with CloudFront origin to it. I am getting an error when I upload below code stack to the cloud formation

Error:ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https' is  Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/DistributionConfig}:

As per the cloudformation documentation above parameter ViewerProtocolPolicy:  redirect-to-https is supported.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
BucketName:
Type: String
Description: Allocate the Bucket Name you want to create it
DefaultRootObject:
Type: String
Description: The Default Path of the index.html Document 
Default: 'index.html' 
ErrorPagePath:
Type: String
Description: The Default path of the error.html Document
Default: '/error.html'


Resources:
mys3bucket:
Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
Properties:
  AccessControl: Private
  BucketName: !Ref BucketName

  WebsiteConfiguration: 
    IndexDocument: !Ref DefaultRootObject
    ErrorDocument: !Ref ErrorPagePath
  #DeletionPolicy: Retain
 ReadPolicy:
 Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
 Properties:
  Bucket: !Ref mys3bucket
  PolicyDocument:
    Statement:
      - Action: 's3:GetObject'
        Effect: Allow
        Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${mys3bucket}/*'
        Principal:
          CanonicalUser: !GetAtt 
CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId

 CloudFrontDistribution:
Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
Properties:
  DistributionConfig:
    CustomErrorResponses:
      - ErrorCode: 403 # not found
        ResponseCode: 404
        ResponsePagePath: !Ref ErrorPagePath
    DefaultCacheBehavior:
      AllowedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
      CachedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
      Compress: true
      DefaultTTL: 3600 # in seconds
      ForwardedValues:
        Cookies:
          Forward: none
        QueryString: false
      MaxTTL: 86400 # in seconds
      MinTTL: 60 # in seconds
      TargetOriginId: s3origin
    ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https'
    DefaultRootObject: !Ref DefaultRootObject
    Enabled: true
    HttpVersion: http2
    Origins:
      - DomainName: !GetAtt 'mys3bucket.DomainName'
        Id: s3origin
        S3OriginConfig:
          OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub 'origin-access- 
 identity/cloudfront/${CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'
    PriceClass: 'PriceClass_All'
  #  ViewerCertificate:
   #   AcmCertificateArn: !Ref AcmCertificateArn
  #    SslSupportMethod: sni-only

 CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity'
Properties:
  CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
    Comment: !Ref mys3bucket


Outputs:
BucketName:
Value:!Ref 'mys3bucket'
Description: Name of the sample Amazon S3 bucket with a lifecycle 
 configuration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small indentation error. `ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https'` should be a child of `DefaultCacheBehavior` you have it under `DistributionConfig`